# MPI_Ibcast + MPI_Test couldn't receive data

Tags: c, mpi

I have a data need to broadcast to workers.
However I can't receive it even I use MPI_Wait instead of MPI_Test, unless I using blocking MPI_Bcast.

I have no idea what happen, I have tried many ways, but none of them work.

Is there any thing wrong in my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main()
{
    int rank, size;
    int data;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    printf("MPI start %d/%d\n", rank, size);

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        sleep(1);
        data = 1;
        printf("MPI %d/%d bcast\n", rank, size);
        MPI_Bcast(&data, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else
    {
        int flag = 0;
        MPI_Request req = MPI_REQUEST_NULL;
        MPI_Status status;
        MPI_Ibcast(&data, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);
        while (flag == 0) {
            MPI_Test(&req, &flag, &status);
            usleep(100 * 1000);
        }
        // MPI_Bcast can be done!
        //MPI_Bcast(&data, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("MPI %d/%d recv bcast data: %d\n", rank, size, data);
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

It will hangup here:

```
MPI start 0/5
MPI start 1/5
MPI start 2/5
MPI start 3/5
MPI start 4/5
MPI 0/5 bcast
```

Comment: Just a small remark: Do not loop on `MPI_Test` unless you a) have useful work to do in the loop, or b) you want the thread to sleep and your MPI implementation doesn't support that properly. Otherwise use `MPI_Wait`.

Comment: Yep, I just use it to stand for some other code, thank you for your advice.

Comment: BTW, is there any way to combine `pthread_cond_wait` and `MPI_Wait` like `select`? I have a loop in a worker thread, I need to wait notifies from `pthread_cond_signal` and `MPI_Send`.

Comment: Not directly. I guess you could do something like sending a message to your own thread and use `MPI_Waitany`, or otherwise do some thread trickery. Pretty sure anything the like requires `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE`.

Comment: hmmmm, It looks like the only way to achieve this is to do thread trickery if I care about the real time notification from both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gilles is absolutely right, MPI explicitly states that

> Unlike point-to-point operations, **nonblocking collective operations do not match with blocking collective operations** [...]

There is a very simple fix though, just replace your `MPI_Bcast` with:

```
MPI_Request req;
MPI_Status status;
MPI_Ibcast(&data, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);
MPI_Wait(&req, &status);
```

Comment: BTW, is there any way to simulate the MPI_Ibcast for the old version MPI which has no implement of MPI 3.0?

Comment: Oh! That's exactly what I want!

Answer (score 2):

i am afraid you cannot simply mix `MPI_Bcast()` on rank 0 and `MPI_Ibcast()` on the other ranks.

Comment: yep, you're right, i just thought there are same simply.